# Atualizar comentários sem carregar a página

Tags: jquery, script

Para cada POST, eu tenho um formulário de comentários. O que preciso fazer é passar o ID do formulário para o script, para poder tratar o comentário no respectivo POST.

Porém para passar o valor para a `div` processar, eu precisaria colocar de alguma forma o ID do novo comentário nessa `div`, para que quando haja um outro comentário, a `div` não seja substituída e sim adicionada.

Esse formulário é enviado ao pressionar a tecla **Enter**. Eu preciso saber como enviar o ID do POST para dentro do script para que fique `$("#myForm"+ valorId).ajaxForm({` ao invés de `$("#myForm9").ajaxForm({`.

Tem alguma forma de enviar o seguinte resultado com uma `div`, para que essa `div` de `id="processa'.$commentId.'` seja mostrada ao invés de chamar uma `div` já definida com ID fixo ?

```
    echo '
    <span>'.$posting.'</span><div class="cimg_box"><img class="comment_img" src="css/images/profile_photo/'.$user['photo'].'"/></div>';
};
```

**Código completo:**

```html
if ($rows > 0){

echo '<div class="comment_all clearfix" style="display: none" id="reply_box'.$post['id_p'].'">';
    while($comment = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query3)){
        echo '
        <div class="comment_box">
            <span>'.$comment['text'].'</span><div class="cimg_box"><img class="comment_img" src="css/images/profile_photo/'.$comment['photo'].'"/></div>
        </div>';
    }

    echo '
    <div id="processa" class="comment_box">

    </div>
   </div>';
  }
                echo '

                <div class="comm_box_reply" >
                    <div class="reply_box"><img class="img_friend2" src="css/images/profile_photo/'.$user['photo'].'"/>
                        <form id="myForm'.$post['id_p'].'" value="'.$post['id_p'].'" name="rform" class="reply_form" action="processing.php" method="post">
                            <textarea name="editor1" id="text'.$post['id_p'].'" onclick="rpbox(this.id, '.$post['id_p'].')" class="imagem_news" placeholder="Your Comment..." ></textarea>
                            <input name="formValue" type="text" value="'.$post['id_p'].'" hidden/>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>



 $(document).ready(function() { 
        $("#processa").hide();
        $("#myForm9").ajaxForm({ /*Preciso modificar aqui para colocar a id do post*/
        target: "#processa",
            success: function(){
                $("#processa").show();
            }
        }); 
    });`

    <?php
        include("config.php");

        if ($_POST['editor1'] != ''):
            $uid = $_SESSION['userId'];
            $postId = $_POST["formValue"];

            if((isset($_POST["editor1"])) ? $_POST["editor1"] : ''){
                $posting = (isset($_POST["editor1"])) ? $_POST["editor1"] : '';
                $date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
                $sql = "INSERT INTO comments (id_c, post_id, author_id , text, date) values ('', '$postId', '$uid', '$posting', '$date')";
                mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
                $query4 = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM `profile` WHERE `id` = '$uid'") or die(mysqli_error($conn));
                $user = mysqli_fetch_array($query4);
                $proc = mysqli_insert_id($conn);
                echo '
                <span>'.$posting.'</span><div class="cimg_box"><img class="comment_img" src="css/images/profile_photo/'.$user['photo'].'"/></div>';
            };

        else:
            echo 'Error!';
        endif;
    ?>
```

Comment: Uma dica, que para mim acho interessante. Separe os seguintes arquivos: HTML, php (dao e controller) e JQuery.

Comment: pra mim nao ficou muito claro... a questao do id pro ajax eu faria assim:
$.ajax({
(...)
data: { 'nomeParam': $("#myForm"+ valorId)

Comment: @adventistaam Sim, estão separados.

Comment: @aa_sp eu tenho um conjunto de posts, e cada um desses posts é aberto a comentários.
Pra fazer a postagem do comentário, eu uso js com a tecla enter, em vez de um botão.

Eu preciso pegar a id do formulário, por exemplo, pra poder tratar esse formulário em específico.

Comment: Por exemplo, esse `echo 'div...` você traria só o resultado para o ajax, e o ajax alimentaria na sua pagina html

Comment: @adventistaam o problema é que quando retorna o resultado, o script mostra apenas o último resultado enviado ao invés de dar o append. Outra coisa é que só atualiza pra quem tá vendo e não para todo mundo.

Comment: Neste caso você pode usar o [pusher](https://pusher.com/) para ver o aviso pra todo mundo